# Bootstrap 4 form not sedning any messages

Tags: php, forms, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap 4 form is not sending any messages, I've uploaded the index.php and contact.php files on the server and I'm not having any response. Would you be able to help me find the problem?

Landing page with simple form

```html
<form id="#contacts" method="POST" class="form" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                   placeholder="Podaj swoje Imię i nazwisko" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="website" name="website"
                   placeholder="Adres strony www" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone"
                   placeholder="Podaj swój numer telefonu" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                   placeholder="Podaj swój email" type="email" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Twoja wiadomość"
              rows="4"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Wyślij</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

contact.php

```php
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

$email_from = 'SEO';
$email_subject = 'Wiadomość kontaktowa z... '
$email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
              "Email: $email.\n".
              "Message: $message.\n";
              "Website: $website.\n";
              "Telephone: $telephone.\n";

$to = "biuro@of.pl";
$headers = "From: $email_from r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email r\n";

mail($to,$email-$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("location: index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is missing `Action`

```
<form id="#contacts" method="POST" class="form" role="form" action="contact.php">
```

Comment: But im having other problem, the whole page is refreshing automatically any 5 sec, do you have any ideas how to stop that mm

Comment: You should post that in another question probably... I'd need to see your javascript if that' happeneing... 

If my answer worked for you, it would be great if you could accept it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, there isnt any javascript in the code. All there is you have above.